# VSCode throw an error when using decorator on overload

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

My code:

```js
declare class DemoApi {
  @someDecorator
  getIndexCards(foo: string, bar: number): Promise<TIndexCards>;
}
```

The error message:

```
A decorator can only decorate a method implementation, not an overload.
```

Solutions that may help:

1. Write a new typescript extension to VSCode
2. a new Typescript Server Plugin. but as the [typescript wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin) says

   > Examples of things language plugins cannot do:
   >   Add new custom syntax to TypeScript
   >   Change how the compiler emits JavaScript
   >   Customize the type system to change what is or isn't an error when running tsc
3. remove `A_decorator_can_only_decorate_a_method_implementation_not_an_overload` code from `tsserver.js`, and it works, but that was not a good idea.

I know that ts will remove all declare code after compiled so decorator for a abstract method was not allow. but i want to write a compiler using babel or something else to compile it and do something with these decorators, the question is vscode (who works with Typescript Language Server) will throw a error tips, that is annoying. so i think there might be a few way to eliminate it

is there any hooks for `tsServer` or any other way to eliminate the error tips in vscode